# What does the number next to favorites mean?

Tags: support, bookmarks

When one of my favourite questions is updated, a little number appears in my profile as in: [image: picture]. What does this number refer to?

Comment: It means there has been activity in six of the questions you marked as favorite.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I don't think that can be right. I only have 11 favourites in the first place, and only two of them have had activity today. And the little number indicator wasn't showing when I looked earlier today.

Comment: Should have been "six activites in the questions you marked as favorite". [This one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/114868/742) was edited; [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/115227/742) had an answer, a delete, and edit, and several comments.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thanks very much. Can you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3):

According to an answer to this meta.SO question: [What does highlighting mean on the profile's “Favorites” tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114274/what-does-highlighting-mean-on-the-profiles-favorites-tab/114277#114277)

> The number next to the tab indicates how many posts have new answers since you last visited the tab.

Arturo Magidin in [his comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3754/what-does-the-number-next-to-favorites-mean#comment14015_3754) has a different explanation:

> Should have been "six activites in the questions you marked as favorite". [This one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/114868/742) was edited; [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/115227/742) had an answer, a delete, and edit, and several comments.

I do not know, which of the two answers is correct. But I  am adding this as an answer so that it will bump the post and there is hope that someone who knows more about this will notice the question.